# Swift 3 Google Map and MapKit API - if users current location has been updated

Tags: ios, swift, maps

I am trying to see whenever the user's location has been updated. I tried many different listeners, but I can't seem to figure this out. 
What would be the most effective and efficient way to test whether the user's location has been updated?

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations[0]

    let lat = location.coordinate.latitude
    let long = location.coordinate.longitude
    print(lat, long)

    let currentLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, long)
    let lastLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((locations.last?.coordinate.latitude)!, (locations.last?.coordinate.longitude)!)

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: lat, longitude: long, zoom: 15)
    self.mapView.animate(to: camera)

    let geocoder = GMSGeocoder()
        if currentLocation.latitude != lastLocation.latitude || currentLocation.longitude != lastLocation.longitude {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Location Update", message: "Current location has been updated", preferredStyle: .alert)

            let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            print("no update change")
        }

    geocoder.reverseGeocodeCoordinate(currentLocation) { (response, error) in
        if let address = response?.firstResult() {
            let lines = address.lines!
            self.currentLocationLabel.text = lines.joined(separator: "\n")
        }
    }

    // self.manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}
```

Comment: didUpdateLocations doesn't works for you?

Comment: is that a bool? Where I can write if didUpdateLocations

Answer (score 1):

i think you just wanna get the user's location on the map right?
you can get the user's location from the mapview and you can do this in didUpdateLocation

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

      if let mylocation = mapview.myLocation{

         //animate the mapview to user's location
         let lat = mylocation.coordinate.latitude
         let long = mylocation.coordinate.longitude
         let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: lat, longitude: long, zoom: 14.0)
         mapview.camera = camera
         mapview.animate(to: camera)

       }

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: this will update the user's location every time the user's location changes?

Comment: Yes. It will also update the mapview when the user's location is updated significantly